# Keykloak-Angular request /Account after token request

Tags: angular, keycloak

Iam working  on an angular and keycloak project. I used exactly this tutorial to integrate keycloak into angular. -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular

My public client ist able to request a token, but also make a request to the keycloak path /account where i have no access to.

Cause of this my app does not start.

I used angular version 5 with the angular-keycloak module 1.3.x

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Pls elaborate what is your problem. I have used Keycloak with angular,might be able to help. Also, share some code related to how you integrated with Keycloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get into contact with the creator of the keycloak-angular package. Turns out it was a planned behaviour to call /account. The creator fixed this issue and it works now pretty well.